$\sqrt{p^*}$ contained in $\Bbb Q(\zeta_p)$
Let $p$ be a prime. I read several times e.g. here that the square root $\sqrt{p^*}$ (where $p^*:=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p$) is contained in $\Bbb Q(\zeta_p)$. Is there a "standard argument" see it?
Looks like "fact from every book on number theory", but I nowhere found a discussion about it? The question is closely related to
this one.
